# Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.6 breaks build process

Tags: msbuild

Just upgraded to Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform from 1.0.5 to 1.0.6

The build process keeps failing

> ASPNETCOMPILER:ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPRUNTIME: Could not find a part of the path 'd:\a\1\s\myapplication\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\bin\roslyn\csc.exe'.
>   Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

There's already a PR to fix this; should be resolved in 1.0.7.  Until then I'm staying on 1.0.5.

https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/pull/14/files